# UIImage VIew Not loading image?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImage on my MyCartViewController. And i have a button on my BlackFacePlatesViewController. I want this button to set the image on the MyCartViewController to another image, however i can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code for the button to set the image on the MyCartViewController:

**EDIT:**

I HAVE 1 BOOL VARIABLE IN VC2 AND WHEN THE BUTTON IS PRESSED IN VC1, I SET THE BOOL AND CREATE VC2. THEN IN THE `VIEWWILLAPPEAR` METHOD, I SET THE IMAGE ACCORDINGLY. HERE IS THE CODE: THANKS

```
- (IBAction)outlet1 {
MyCartViewController * imageCart = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];
imageCart.displayImage = YES;

}
```

BUTTON THAT THE USER PRESSES ^

THIS IS TO SWITCH PAGES:

```
- (IBAction)myCart:(id)sender; {
MyCartViewController * first = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];
first.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:first animated:YES];
[first release];

}
```

THIS IS THE `VIEWWILLAPPEAR` METHOD IN VC2:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
if (self.displayImage == YES) {
    UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle_3.png"];
    [outletImageView setImage:myImage];
}

}
```

WOULD THIS WORK? THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP EVERYBODY!!!

Comment: If you post more code, that will help. You mentioned something about moving to the next page. Are you sure the object/VC is loaded?

Comment: hmmm... im not sure how to test that.. But ill post the code to switch pages and the viewDidLoad method!

Comment: `cart` is not being allocated before you tell it to change it's image. I'll post some code in an answer to try and help out.

Comment: cart.newImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle_1.png"]; Where and how did you declare this 'cart'?

Comment: This is just declared in the .h file and the code for it is:

MyCartViewController * cart;
@property...
synthesize etc.
And this was declared in BlackFacePlatesViewController

Comment: `- (IBAction)outlet1` is a pointless method. All it does is create a `MyCartViewController`, and then leak it. You need to set the relevant properties when you create the method, and THEN push the view onto the navigation controller. Also, this is **NOT** all of the code. Please post your .h and .m files to look through everything, as there *has* to be something else wrong somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allocating your object `cart` properly, and `cart2` has nothing to do with `cart`, apart from being a similar class. You should just make an instance variable in the header file that's a `UIImage` which holds the image you want to use in your next `UIView`, and set it when you use `presentModalViewController:` Try this. In your .h file,

```
@interface MyCartViewController : UIViewController {
  UIImage * imageForNextView;
}
```

In your .m file,

```
- (IBAction)outlet1:(id)sender; {
  imageForNextView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle_1.png"];
}

- (IBAction)outlet2:(id)sender; {
  imageForNextView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paddle_2.png"];
}

- (IBAction)myCart:(id)sender; {
  MyCartViewController * cart2 = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];
  cart2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  cart2.newImage.image = imageForNextView;
  [self presentModalViewController:cart2 animated:YES];
  [cart2 release];
}
```

I made 2 button methods to illustrate the point of switching the image based on which button was pushed. Remember that `imageNamed:` caches the `UIImage`, so if you have a lot, you may have to start looking into other loading methods, all of which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This should solve your problem.

***Edit:*** Try this. In your .h file,

```
@interface MyCartViewController : UIViewController {
  NSString * nameOfImage;
  UIImageView * imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nameOfImage;
```

In the .m file,

```
@synthesize nameOfImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad; {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nameOfImage];
}
```

Then, when you push to the view, try:

```
- (IBAction)myCart:(id)sender; {
  MyCartViewController * cart2 = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];
  cart2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  cart2.nameOfImage = @"Paddle_2.png";
  [self presentModalViewController:cart2 animated:YES];
  [cart2 release];
}
```

***Edit2:*** [This](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/splitview-application-in-ipad/) is a tutorial about how to use a `UISplitViewController`, which has a similar idea, where you press a `UITableViewCell`, and it changes an image in another `UIView`. You should look through this, and see if it can help your project.

Also, try:

```
- (IBAction)myCart:(id)sender; {
  MyCartViewController * cart2 = [[MyCartViewController alloc]init];
  cart2.nameOfImage = @"Paddle_2.png";
  [self pushViewController:cart2 animated:YES];
  [cart2 release];
}
```

This is another way to move to a new `UIView`, which may work.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: First off... THanks a lot for the help i really appreciate it, but i did what you suggested by removing cart. And i also tried your code, but i cant get it to work? Do you have any other ideas!

Comment: If you need more help, can you post more of your code? Like the `.h` and `.m` files for `MyCartViewController`, and for the above class?

Comment: In your new post, it does not look like you have `@synthesize newImage;` anywhere. Do you?

Comment: yep i sure do.. Do you have any other ideas? Some one else said i had to save it in a dictionary and then reload it. Would you do it this way?

Comment: No, that is definitely too much work. I think I'll just edit your above code, and you can use that. If it works, just accept my current answer, as that will be fine.

Comment: Alright, looking through your code, in you `viewWillAppear:` method, you are overwriting the image you are setting in the previous view. So this can be cleaned up, I just want to know why you are setting the image in the `viewWillAppear:` method before I fix it.

Comment: You could comment out the stuff in your viewWillAppear: method and check if that changes anything. As @MSgambel said you are overwriting the image there and maybe that's the part where your problem lies.

Comment: @MSgambel i was setting it  in the 'viewWillAppear:' method because i had this problem a while back and never got it to work, and someone on the apple dev forums told me to put that code there. And i know what overwriting something is, but can you explain it so that i know if i have this problem again please? And once again i would just like to say thank you very much for the help you guys!!!!!

Comment: Well, you are setting the image before the view is pushed, and `viewWillAppear:` is called just before the view will appear, and since you have a line of code which sets the image in the `viewWillAppear:` method, it is overwriting the image you set before the view was pushed. Comment out that line in the `viewWillAppear:` method which sets the image, and see if it works.

Comment: @MSgambel ok i understand what you mean. But i comment out the line [[self newImage] setImage:theImage]; and the image isnt set when i switch to the view, but even when i press the button it wont set either? I'm not sure what i was doing wrong.

Comment: Try my new fix. It will work, as it is an easier way of doing this.

Comment: @MSgambel nah no hope still :( but hey bud i really appreciate all the help! :D

Comment: Are you sure? Because I use that code all the time. Do you have your nib hooked up properly? Are you setting the image anywhere else in your .m file? Is there any other relevant code?

Comment: @MSgambel ya i triple checked the code. And yep i do have my nib hooked up good. Um... nope im not setting it anywhere except where you showed me in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: In my `viewDidLoad:` example, change `nameOfImage` to `@"Paddle_2.png"` in the `imageNamed:` method. This will tell you if you have hooked it up properly. Also, add `NSLog(@"The string image name is: %@", nameOfImage);` to your `viewDidLoad` method, and see what it says.

Comment: ok i did what you said about changing it to `@"Paddle_2.png"` in the `viewDidLoad` method, and i also added the NSLog and it says that the string image name is Paddle_2.png.

Comment: even when i dont press the button, the image shows up when i switch views. I have a button that is hooked up to an outlet1 method and i want to press it and then switch to the MyCartViewController page and have the image be there.

Comment: Then you need only add the line: 1cart2.nameOfImage = @"Paddle_2.png";1 to that button method. Also, try putting the line `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nameOfImage];` in your `viewWillAppear:` method instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: hmm.... this darn code still isnt working!:( ok here. let me post my code for both of the files and if you dont mind could you please take a look thru them and see if I'm writing the code properly? And hey bud i would just like to say thanks again!! Its hard to find nice people like you that will help me until it works, most people would just stop helping me but i would just like to say thanks man!

Comment: No problem. Just post your code, both file, the .h, and .m, and I'll take a look at it and see if I can fix it. Since I won't be able to see the nibs, I will assume that you can do that on your own.

Comment: ok awesome thanks so much! they are posted in my question. and yep i triple checked my nibs! And someone else said that i should do this using a Boolean variable do you suggest i do that or should i just stick to your way? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like you've posted anything new. You should post the whole .h and .m files. It is at this point that the only way we will figure this out is if you post that.

Comment: @MSgambel hey bud could i do this will a boolean variable? I have tried and nothing will work. Could it be with the way i switch pages that it wont let the image appear? Here ill post this code that someone else gave me and could you please check it out to see if i did everything A Okay? Thanks a lot! i appreciate all the time and effort you are going through to help me! Thanks again code master! ;)

Comment: @MSgabel I FIGURED IT OUT!!!! :D i was messing something up with my ivars!! I was overriding or pushing on a different view. I allocated and had to init my cart ivar in the `init` method to be able to use it in both the `outlet1` method and in the `myCart` method!! Thanks so much for all of your help i really appreciate it!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Great! Finally! I was getting worried there might have been deeper problems! Glad to help. Any other questions you have, post them here, and I'll try to help if I can!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this line of code is actually executed? Did you check that while debugging or with an NSLog?
If not then check the reference to the action 'outlet1'.

What is cart?
What is cart.newimage?
How are those linked to the UIImagaeView that is part of 'the next page'?

You may need to force the redraw via setNeedsDisplay.

Assuming your cart.newImage is the UIImageView object:

```
[cart.newimage setNeedsDisplay]; //might do the trick.
```

However, that is a bit view of code to really understand the issue.

Comment: yeah it is getting called. Well the outlet1 method is because i put an NSLog in the method and it printed out. Cart is my object that is created from MYCartVIewController, which is the second page. BlackFacePlatesViewController is the 1st view. cart.newImage is my UIIMageView that i want updated which is on the second page. And i tried your provided code in the outlet1: method and it didnt work. Any more ideas? And THanks for the help!!!:D

Comment: With 'the second page' you mean that BlackFacePlatesViewController is displayed next?

Has it been created/initialized already?

Really, you do not show much code. What do you do with the newImage object within BlackFacePlatesViewController's viewDidLoad und initWith... und loadView und viewWillAppear bzw. viewDidAppear Methoden?

Comment: nope the second page would be the MyCartViewController. And i dont do anything with those methods, i was asking if i was missing something. Am i supposed to add code to one of those methods? Thanks

Comment: now that you added some more code.

your code titled with "switch pages", does that actually switch the page and bring it up?

Comment: (pls ignore the comment above) 
Your code titled with "switch pages", does that actually switch the page and bring it up?

(LOL, the question sounds stupid so far :)

Well, why do you alloc a new instance of the MyCartViewController class?
You are actually creating a completely new instance and bring that one up front. 
What ever you may have assigned to that other instance, where "cart" is referring to, is naturally unknown to the new instance in the local variable "cart2". 

How and when did you allocate cart and why don't you use it in myCart: ?

Basically this is what MSgambel said already

Comment: hey i re read your post above and i see what you are saying, but when you switch views dont you have to create and allocate the copy of the class `cart2` in the method that actually gets called when you switch the page right? If so, then how can i switch the pages still and still use the same object? Thanks a lot!